# Is it possible to provide animation progress to angular animations?

Tags: css, angular, angular-animations

I have a quite simple animation which was implemented using the Angular animations framework. Instead of simply triggering the animation and waiting 0.15 seconds until completion i want to provide some custom animation progress value.

```
animations: [
    trigger('animateMargin', [
      state('min', style({ marginTop: '25px' })),
      state('max', style({ marginTop: '50px' })),
      transition('min => max', [ animate('0.15s ease-in') ]),
      transition('max => min', [ animate('0.15s ease-out') ])
    ])
  ]
```

Is it possible to tell Angular that i want my animation to be complete to 64% or to 27% for example instead of using fixed timings?

Comment: do you have dynamic progress value then calculate time?

Comment: @joyBlanks The dynamic progress value is completely user dependent and is calculated from the amount the user has scrolled.